# why firebase registration with textwatcher is not working?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, textwatcher

I'm building the registration activity in which I use a textwatcher to see if email or password are empty, if all is correct is supposed to go through firebase auth and also set the opacity of register button to 100%, but it doesn't do anything

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)
        val email = email_editText_register.text.toString()
        val password = password_editText_register.text.toString()
        registrar_button_register.alpha = 0.5f
        registrar_button_register.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                val emailInput = email_editText_register.getText().toString().trim()
                val passwordInput = password_editText_register.getText().toString().trim()

                registrar_button_register.setEnabled(!emailInput.isNotEmpty() && !passwordInput.isNotEmpty())

            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

                registrar_button_register.setOnClickListener {

                    registrar_button_register.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(200)
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

                        //createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener {
                            if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d("register", "Successfully created with uid: ${it.result?.user?.uid}")
                            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, Inicio::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {

                            Log.d("main", "Failed to create user: ${it.message}")
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the email already exist or it is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                }

            }
        })
```

this is the layout

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/username_editText_register"
            android:hint="Usuario"
            style="@android:style/Widget.AutoCompleteTextView"
            android:background="#F3F3F3" android:textAlignment="viewStart" android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/email_editText_register"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/email_editText_register" android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_editText_register"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/email_editText_register"
            android:hint="E-mail"
            android:background="#F3F3F3" android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Registrar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#CC196AE0"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold" android:id="@+id/registrar_button_register"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/password_editText_register"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password_editText_register" android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_editText_register"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="Volver"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/volver_textView_register" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/registrar_button_register"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/registrar_button_register"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registrar_button_register"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="14dp" android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#050505"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/password_editText_register" android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username_editText_register"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/username_editText_register"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/username_editText_register" android:background="#f3f3f3"
            android:hint="Contraseña" android:textSize="14dp"/>
```

after the imputs are correct the button should be 100% oppacity, also the registration should work and then go to the next activity called "Inicio"

thank you for everyone who has help this is the final code with everything fixed just in case somebody need it:

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)




    registrar_button_register.setEnabled(false)
registrar_button_register.animate().alpha(0.5f).setDuration(200)
    val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {

        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            val emailInput = email_editText_register.getText().toString().trim()
            val passwordInput = password_editText_register.getText().toString().trim()
            registrar_button_register.setEnabled(emailInput.isNotEmpty() && passwordInput.isNotEmpty())
            val isEnabled = emailInput.isNotEmpty() && passwordInput.isNotEmpty()
            registrar_button_register.setEnabled(isEnabled)
            if (isEnabled) {
                registrar_button_register.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(200)
            } else {
                registrar_button_register.animate().alpha(0.5f).setDuration(200)
            }
        }
    }
email_editText_register.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
password_editText_register.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
Toast.makeText(this, "d", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    registrar_button_register.setOnClickListener {
        val email = email_editText_register.text.toString()
        val password = password_editText_register.text.toString()
        Log.d("Register", "Email is: " + email)
        Log.d("Register", "password is: $password")
        email_editText_register.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        password_editText_register.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

            //createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d("register", "Successfully created with uid: ${it.result?.user?.uid}")
                Toast.makeText(this, "td", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, Inicio::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {

                Log.d("main", "Failed to create user: ${it.message}")
                Toast.makeText(this, "the email already exist or it is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }
```

Comment: For which element You're using TextWatcher ?

Comment: i would like that whenever password/email updates if it follows the statement the button would enable and change it opacity

Comment: @Ashish I was trying to this in Kotlin https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vy_4sZ6JVHM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to enable the button in case that both fields is not empty, so it should be:

```
registrar_button_register.setEnabled(emailInput.isNotEmpty() && passwordInput.isNotEmpty())
```

And you need to add textwatchers to edit text fields not button.
You should create instance of TextWatcher and attach it to edittexts, some thing like this:

```
    val textWatcher = object: TextWatcher {

        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            val emailInput = email_editText_register.getText().toString().trim()
            val passwordInput = password_editText_register.getText().toString().trim()
            val isEnabled = emailInput.isNotEmpty() && passwordInput.isNotEmpty()
            registrar_button_register.setEnabled(isEnabled)
            if(isEnabled) {
                registrar_button_register.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(200)
            }
            else {
                registrar_button_register.animate().alpha(0.5f).setDuration(200)
            }
        }
    }
    email_editText_register.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    password_editText_register.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    registrar_button_register.setOnClickListener {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

                //createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d("register", "Successfully created with uid: ${it.result?.user?.uid}")
                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, Inicio::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {

                    Log.d("main", "Failed to create user: ${it.message}")
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the email already exist or it is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
    }
```

Comment: it works but not the auth of firebase? works without textwatcher

Comment: Do you receive fail or complete from FirebaseAuth?

Comment: i don't receive nothing in logcat

Comment: Put break point on "FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword" line and run in debug mode, and see if on button click you stoped at this line.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)

Comment: the problem now is that if auth is correct the textwatcher doesnt work, and if the text watcher works the auth doesnt...

Comment: Put val email = email_editText_register.text.toString()
            val password = password_editText_register.text.toString() before FirebaseAuth but inside onClickListener

Comment: i also had to change the val email and password and their log.d, I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

I think you got confused. I think you are using the addTextChangedListener on a Button, and not on a EdiText.

The addTextChangedListener method fires when text changes, and your button text never changes.

What you have to do is implement the same textChangedListener object on both email and password object.

Comment: Davis if you read from Alex answer you can see he already described

Comment: Ya, this is just a short answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing firebase authentication in asynchronous manner.So need to do firebase authentication in synchronous (using Task.wait()) manner.